# Allow user to add a new link to their website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, href

**Question**

How could i allow a user to add a new link to an already existing list of links permanently. Preferably the new link would be written directly to the HTML document without the need for a database to store the links, if possible.

I do not want to use a Content Management System like, WordPress as i feel this negates any possibility of learning how to do such tasks and breeds laziness. (My opinion)

**Background**

I am creating a website for someone, who i would like to be able to update parts of their website without my help.

All they need to be able to do is add a new link to a current list of links on one web page. The page is protected and only accessible to them once a secure password is entered.

This is how the links are displayed, all i would need is, for a new link to be appended to the bottom and saved permanently to the html page.

[image]

**Markup**

```
<div class="content">
  <div id="media">
    <h3>Clients</h3>
    <h2><a href="http://www.purplegeckoevents.com">Purple Gecko Events</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="http://www.plymouthvolksfest.co.uk/">Plymouth Volksfest</a> </h2>
    <h2><a href="http://moriaty.co.uk/">Moriaty</a> </h2>
    <h2><a href="http://www.landofthegiantsmusic.co.uk/">Land of the Giants</a> </h2>
    <h2><a href="https://www.facebook.com/betamaxlive">Betamax</a> </h2>
    <h2><a href="https://www.facebook.com/hauntthewoodsofficia">Haunt the Woods</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="http://www.minglemusic.co.uk/">Mingle Music Agency</a> </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As the question is tagged PHP, have a look a the php code that generates this html and at the database where the links and descriptions are stored and go from there.

Comment: what you're referring to is known as a 'CMS' but plenty of these exist already, wordpress would be one example

Comment: Do you want this to just work temporarily in their browser on their computer (in which case you could look into cookies/localStorage), or is this supposed to be permanent data (which is what I suspect. In which case you'll need some server-side script (e.g. using PHP) and perhaps a database on a server in which to store this data)

Comment: @Shai It needs to be permanent, and i would prefer not to have to use a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a db to store all these links.

And then you can :

1. To display links - use php to fetch all the links from db and show them.
   http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp
2. To add links - use form to take input of link(the href,title etc) and insert in db
   http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Although i was hoping not to have to do it this way, this is the solution i've gone for. Thank you @thecbuilder.

Comment: @DanCundy You can go various other methods like file handling(not recommended) etc.. .. And you are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing for you to do would be to migrate to WordPress and have them use that to administer their webpage. This is one simple request now, but later your client will want to add an image. Or delete an image. Or change the title on the homepage, etc.

Either you have them email requests to you and you charge for it (in which case you still might want to use WordPress to save you time), or, you set them up on WordPress and do the initial design and then teach them how to use WordPress for simple tasks like adding links, letting them request bigger redesigns from you as future projects.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a simple jQuery function to perform this with a text box:

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="text" id="url">
<button id="urlsubmit">Add URL</button>

<script>
$('#urlsubmit').on('click', function(){
$("div#media").append( "<h2><a href='"+$('#url').text()+"id='"+$("#name").text()+"'/></h2>");
});
</script>
```

Excuse any typos ;)

Comment: This will add the link to the page FOR THAT BROWSER SESSION, but is not a solution to allow the user to permanently add content to the page, which is what the OP is asking for.